# Concrete5 Appending Paths

Tags: concrete5

I wanted to post out to the community in an effort to try and pin down a recent issue I've been having in regards to pulling in custom fonts.

When I initially set up my site to try and import a custom font, I followed the guide here (http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/designers/how-to-add-a-custom-font-face-to-your-theme/) and thankfully I was able to pull in my fonts.css file that I needed.

Unfortunately, just recently I went ahead and made some customizations to the theme I was using (Under Page Settings > Design). After I had saved those changes however, I noticed that my fonts we're no longer being referenced and I was getting 404 errors when trying to pull that fonts.css file.

Now in my header file, I was referencing the fonts.css file relatively which worked until I made the customizations to the theme. Now it seems as though it's changed the 'location/directory' of where these pages, or at least the header file is. The differences in what I've put into the header file, and what's being appended are below.

Before:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php  echo $this->getStyleSheet('../fonts/raleway/fonts.css')?>" />
```

Now:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/index.php/ccm/system/css/page/157/../fonts/raleway/fonts.css" />
```

In particular, I'm noticing that

```
/index.php/ccm/system/css/page/157/
```

is now being appended, which is obviously causing the reference to fail. My question is, is there any way that I can reset concrete5 so that I will stop appending this reference, or a way to set a direct path (which is /application/files/cache/css/fonts/raleway/fonts.css) in my header file?

As for other information, I do have Pretty URL's enabled all appropriately (as far as I can tell). And I've set the location of all my pages within their own page, rather than all being built from the index.php page.

If there's anything you guys might need from me, just feel free to let me know. Again, if there's any way that I can get this resolved, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite its name, getStylesheet in concrete 5.7 and greater only works with LESS files, not .css files. It's also not set up to handle ".." in the path of files. If you pass a .css file to getStylesheet it will run the file through the LESS parser, which may double-encode things. You might not notice any problems with this, but it's best to avoid it altogether if possible.

Here's how I would add a custom font face to my theme.

First, make sure your theme's directory contains the "fonts/fonts.css" file with your custom font face directives in it.

Then, include the file this way in your theme:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $view->getThemePath()?>/fonts/fonts.css" />
```

This will only work if "fonts" the directory appears at the root level within your theme's directory – but it should be all you need to do.

Comment: Sorry I mark the answer as useful, this account is too little. But this worked just fine. Thanks again. Didn't realize that getStyleSheet was running it through a LESS parser, which would be why that string was being appended. Just seemed odd to me that it worked on the first attempt. 

Either way thanks again! Much appreciated.